# setAttribute is undefined ,why?

Tags: function, properties, undefined, getelementsbyclassname, setattribute

This is my code follow:

[in html]```

```
[in css]```
.myclass {
   width:50%;
}```

[in js] `function changewidth() { let mynodes = document.getElementsByClassName('.myclass'); mynodes.setAttribute('width','100%'); }`

then, when this function be run, it display:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined, when reading 'setAttribute'

what happen and how to correct ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the myNodes variable is undefined meaning JavaScript cant find it anywhere because it doesn't exist.

Remove the dot(.) in

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.myclass')
```

It should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')
```